# Django date.day queryset lookup

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

Trying to get some objects in queryset based on the date.day

```
#Model

class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    from = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    ...

#view

    day = 2
    entryes = Entry.objects.all()

    #works
    day_entryes = entryes.filter(from__day=day)

    #do not work
    day_entryes = entryes.filter(from__day__lte=day)
```

I got the following error:

```
Join on field 'from' not permitted. Did you misspell 'day' for the lookup type?
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't support filter methods like `__lt`, `__gt`, `__in` on date field attributes. There's a ticket about this [#6439](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6439).

You can do the filter you want using [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
day = 2
Entry.objects.extra(where=["EXTRACT(day FROM from) <= %s"], params=[day])
```

I've tested the above with MySQL, the syntax may be different for other SQL backends.